WFS layer security in GeoServer
I am using GeoServer version 2.26.1.
I have a vector dataset and visualizing it on OpenLayers through WFS layer.
I want to secure the WFS layer that is available in Inspect>Network>Fetch. What should I need to do and how many alternative are there for this, that anonymous can visualize my WFS layer but unable to access it?


You might use WMS for the anonymous user (just a picture, no data), and WFS for the logged-in one. Make sure you lock down the GeoServer security so that one cannot just figure out the WMS endpoint, and then change the request manually, to get the data they want (yes, there is plenty of skilled people that would figure that out quickly).

Also be aware that the WMS getFeatureInfo request can be utilized to get features almost like a WFS request, so you better uncheck the "Queryable" checkbox in the WMS settings if you don't want some random internet guy to be able to harvest your data. Drawback is that you won't be able to display popups for your own data in your own application.

As Ian already pointed out, you can not make your application have anonymous access to your endpoint and at the same time prevent others to anonymously access the same endpoint. But you can make it harder for an intruder.
If you are concerned with an intruder "stealing" your map layer by adding it to their own map, you can configure CORS to only allow requests from your domain. It won't do anything against stealing the data though.
If you are concerned with an intruder downloading all your data using wget or curl or similar, you can not prevent that, as CORS only applies to browsers. But you can make it a bit harder by adding some sort of required token. It could be in a HTTP header or a cookie. The token must be generated and verified server side. An easy way of doing it it using a session cookie.

Put your application and geoserver behind the same reverse proxy so they share cookie domain.
Have your application set a server side encrypted cookie. Calls to Geoserver does not set the cookie.
The browser will automatically send the cookie in each request to Geoserver when they share cookie domain.
Make the proxy verify the cookie before forwarding the request to Geoserver. If the session cookie is missing or badly signed or expired or doesn't not contain the expected payload, return an error response (without any details of why it failed)

This will require the intruder to first figure out that a session cookie must be present and at least make a call to your application first to get the session cookie, but it does not prevent the intruder to use the browser to download your data, as it will have the session cookie. In curl and similar the intruder will have to make two calls, one to get the cookie and another one to steal your data. You can complicate this scheme further by adding checks to HTTP-headers that a browser would set, but not curl. Still, it won't be foolproof as a decent hacker would mimic a browser's headers just to get round such defense.
Another way to complicate it further is setting custom HTTP headers in your client side code that are verified in the Proxy. But as the client side code is readable to the intruder, it is also a weak defense. But if the code is obfuscated to make it hard to read what the code actually does or how the header's payload is calculated you lose a couple of more unskilled intruders.
Use only POST requests to Geoserver, as browsers send GET requests when navigating. There is no feature in Geoserver to turn off GET requests, so you have to block it in the proxy. Still, it won't prevent much as browsers can send POST requests, for instance from the console and would then include your session cookie, but it prevents an intruder from simply enter an URL in the browser.
If you implement everything above, you have probably defended yourself against most normal Gis users that just happen to find your map and wants to download the data for themselves, but it does not take that much of an effort to circumvent the security measures if they are just somewhat aware of how HTTP works.
Best defense though is probably what Andrea pointed out, to disable WFS and use WMS and disable featureInfo (or have no attributes exposed), but that may not fulfil your application's requirements.
EDIT: Even if you settle for WMS you must disable all text based mime types for WMS. Geoserver can deliver WMS responses in various json and XML formats, which will return features, effectively makes it almost like WFS. The setting can be done at server level under WMS settings (allowed mime typs for getMap request). Only allow those who are just images.
EDIT2: A simple alternative to custom HTTP headers that does not require a proxy is using basic authentication. In that case you:

Define a user in Geoserver
Assign the proper rights in Geoserver
In your application (client side) you send the user/password as a basic authentication header in each request to Geoserver

Still you are vulnerable to simple attacks that checks in browser webtools which headers are sent and can just copy the value or examine the code to find the password. But if the password is obfuscated it could deter some attackers.

many thanks for explaining this .... so well

You can't do that - if your app can see the data anonymously then so can everyone else. That's just the way the web works.
